# Update of one list automatically updates another list

Tags: c#

I have one original list and two temporary lists.
Based on certain condition, I am adding data from the original list(after modifying certain values) to these temp lists. But changes made in one temp list via this copy operation is updating the other temp list as well.

```
List<UserLMSSubFunc> lstUserLMSSubFunc = null;
List<UserLMSSubFunc> lstUserLMSSubFuncTemp1 = new List<UserLMSSubFunc>();
List<UserLMSSubFunc> lstUserLMSSubFuncTemp2 = new List<UserLMSSubFunc>();

foreach (Constructor subFnc in originalList)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in OriginalList)
    {
        if (kv.Value.ToUpper() == subFnc.SubFuncCode.ToUpper())
        {
            if (subFnc.FuncCode == null)
            {
                subFnc.FuncCode = kv.Key;
                templist1.Add(subFnc);
            }
            else
            {
                subFnc.FuncCode = kv.Key;
                Templist2.Add(subFnc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you define those lists.

Comment: @MartinHeralecký updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the data in your lists is changing is due to the reference / value type mishmash. Your lists hold only a reference to an object inside that list. Therefore whenever you change your object which you have pulled from one of the lists I suspect it is the same object which is located in the other two as well, hence the change which seemingly propagates itself across the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Use Setter

```
private var temp1 = new List<Package>();    

public List<Package> temp1
{
    set { temp1 = value; 
          update your temp2}
    get { return temp1; }
}
```